# How can I change Visual Studio 2012 Express item templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

For example I wan't my classes and interfaces to be StyleCop compliant. In non-express editions we can find and change the class template at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class

But it doesn't work for express edition.

Comment: Doesn't work as isn't there or isn't applied?

Comment: Actually I have both Express and Ultimate installed and I've installed Utilmate first. So I don't know if Express would create the path. Now it's there but isn't applied.

Comment: Try `devenv /installvstemplates` (with the express `devenv`) to apply them.

Comment: It was `VWDExpress.exe`, so I tried `VWDExpress.exe /installvstemplates` but doesn't work again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are in this folder for 2012 web express edition

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ItemTemplates
```

And this for 2012 windows express edition

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ItemTemplates
```

Answer (score 2):

Caveat when updating templates that require you to edit the .vstemplate file (such as [multi-file templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247115.aspx)) in 2012 Express editions:

In Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2012 (WDExpress.exe), I have had no luck updating Item Templates using the method in [How to: Update Existing Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185319.aspx) (under "Manually Updating an Existing Template"), which entails copying the updated .zip file to

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\My Exported Templates
```

What turned out to work instead, was to copy the .zip file to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ItemTemplates\VisualC\1033
```

(as described by A. Karimi), and then running

```
wdexpress /installvstemplates
```

on the "Developer Command-Line" as Administrator. (If you do not do this as Administrator, the process will fail, and a dialog is shown with the unhelpful error message "The operation could not be completed".)

Guess: It seems that successful installation can verified by checking if the template .zip file has been copied to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ItemTemplatesCache\VisualC\1033
```