# catel project templates (VS2012 express)

Tags: catel

I would like to give a try with Catel. I saw those fine project templates in the [docu](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+the+project+templates) but can't install them (Extension Manager doesn't find anything searching for catel).
I have downloaded the 3.7 setup [here](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/releases/tag/3.7) and installed it but i do not have any project templates.

Tried also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854831/how-can-i-change-visual-studio-2012-express-item-templates) but still have only the Item-Templates and no project-templates.

Has anybody an idea how to accomplish this?
How can i install project-templates?

Thanks

Comment: I was working on this yesterday, what a coincidence. I tried uploading the vsix to the visual studio gallery this evening, but no luck. Will keep trying and let you know when I succeeded.

It is weird, the installer *should* support VS express. Will see what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first on-line project templates are now available. I have added support for the express edition in config, but not sure if that fully works.

Just search for Catel in the on-line template section of visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

@Users: The project generated with the Catel-online-template does not contain Catel references and will not compile.
We have to run nuget on the new Catel project and install Catel.Core, Catel.MVVM and Catel.Extensions.Controls (for a WPF project) to compile and run.

Comment: When you create a new project with the template, a readme.txt will open on your screen telling you exactly what to do. Didn't it show up at your screen?

Comment: Great to hear :-) You might be interested in this as well: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Getting+started+with+WPF